# error from GetResourceModel()

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am getting the error listed below when the code reaches the line containing

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel(’sales/order_collection’)->addAttributeToSelect(’*’);
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttributeToSelect() on boolean in....

I got the code from an e-book ""php|architect's Guide to Programming Magento Commerce" by Mark Kimsel.

I want to utilize the Magento data access Classes to get data for CRM and accounting. I need to know more about how Magento works and specifically more about the Class properties and methods and how to call them.
I would appreciate suggestions for resources for learning how to do this.??

Kind Regards...

Comment: It looks like `getResourceModel` is returning a boolean rather than an object. Have you looked at the API for this library you're using?

Comment: StackOvrerflow is for solve questions about programming and not for ask for "tutorials, books and external resources"...

Comment: Your call seems fine, what's strange are those apostrophes in getResourceModel call. Please make sure those are actual apostrophes (`'`) and not backticks (`\``). These things are known to happen when you copy paste the code from ebooks.

Comment: ^^ yes - if this is literally your code then the backticks will be your problem

Comment: Thank you Mladen Ilic, My apostrophes do seem to be backticks. And I did copy and paste from a .pdf.

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered via a comment. 
Thank you Mladen Ilic, My apostrophes do seem to be backticks. And I did copy and paste from a .pdf.